# Extract folder contents from file.tar using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to extract the contents of a folder within a tarball using PHP. I am using the following PHP to download and extract the archive:

```
<?php

function wget($address,$filename) {
    file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($address));
}

$newdir = 'test';

echo '<br>Downloading latest gzipped WordPress tarball';

wget('http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz', 'latest.tar.gz');

echo '<br>about to Extract from gz';

// decompress from gz
$p = new PharData('latest.tar.gz');
$p->decompress(); // creates files.tar

echo '<br>Extracted from gz';

// unarchive from the tar
$phar = new PharData('latest.tar');
echo '<br>Un-TARd';
$phar->extractTo($newdir); 

echo '<br>Complete';


?>
```

My problem is that this script extracts the tarball into `/test/wordpress` whereas I need it to extract to `/test/`. I have read through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/phardata.extractto.php) documentation on the PHP.net Manual and replaced part of my code to meet one of the examples there. The code I had was:

`$phar->extractTo($newdir);`

And I changed that to:

`$phar->extractTo($newdir, 'wordpress');`

But that didn't work. The PHP script processed through to the end but the `/test/` directory was empty.
The aim of this is to create a one-click WordPress install on our local dev server.

Comment: Please do not abuse the code snippet tools. They are for HTML/CSS/JS only.

Comment: @JohnConde Apologies, didn't realise they aren't intended for PHP!

Comment: `$phar = new PharData($p);`

Comment: @AlivetoDie gives a 500 error after extracting from .gz - presumably can't find the file?

Comment: @JohnConde can you substantiate your comment about code snippet tool use? I'm shocked that SO would impose such a restriction.

Comment: It's not a restriction arbitrarily put in place. It only *works* for HTML/CSS/JavaScript. You can't use it for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the thread is very old and you probably found solution but maybe I'll save someone else time.

Funcion `extractTo` expects slash at the end of directory name you want to extract.

So `$phar->extractTo($newdir, 'wordpress/');` should work.